# Games-Howell Post-Hoc Test in userfriendlyscience package: no output, just NA

Tags: r, r-markdown, anova, posthoc

I am running a one-way ANOVA in R and the homogeneity of variance assumption is violated. After running a signficant Welch's test, I am trying to run Games-Howell Post Hoc test in R. I am using the oneway function in the userfriendlyscience package. When I run my code, the one-way ANOVA runs, but the post hoc test output does not return anything other than NA. Any suggestions on how to fix my code?

Sample Data

```
>head(dat)
    Region     Composite
    1          4.14
    2          3.54
    2          3.75
    3          3.06
    1          4.49
    2          3.99
```

My output:

```
diff ci.lo ci.hi  t df  p
2-1   NA    NA    NA NA NA NA
3-1   NA    NA    NA NA NA NA
3-2   NA    NA    NA NA NA NA
```

My code:

```
library(userfriendlyscience)

dat$Region <- as.factor(dat$Region)
one.way <- oneway(y = dat$Composite, x = dat$Region, posthoc = "games- 
howell")
one.way
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include sample data that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I used to post comments that explained in detail why I thought questions should be closed but then there was an opinion expressed by the "management" that this was "unwelcoming", so you should just read the multiple help pages to figure out why.

Comment: Done! Hopefully that works.

Comment: My guess is that you have one or more NA values in your data and probably you need to do na.rm or similar for that package.  In R any missings when calculating statistics generally yield NA unless you specifically tell the function how to handle.

Comment: Thank you! I will check that out. I'm still getting the hang of R. I appreciate the input.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I looked into handling the missing values. Although the description of the function doesn't mention it, there can be no missing values in the variable. Problem solved. Thank you!